# XML serialization of an array of different objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Previously, I used an external service, and received from them a response something similar to this XML:

```
<ns0:response xmlns:ns0='http://ws.gp.mnpartners.kz/services/bvu'>
    <data>
        <item>
            <person>
                <request>
                    <number>860517450246</number>
                    <surname>Foo</surname>
                    <name>Bar</name>
                    <birthDate>1986-05-17</birthDate>
                </request>
            </person>
        </item>
        <item>
            <comapany>
                <request>
                    <companyId>010940000162</companyId>
                    <fullName>SomeCompanyName</fullName>
                </request>
            </comapany>
        </item>
    </data>
</ns0:response>
```

Deserialization was very simple, there was a Response class that contained an array of data type, the data type consists of the person and company fields. Since each element contained the company and person type, the deserialization was successful.

Example of my classes:

```
public class Response
{
    public Data[] dataField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("item", IsNullable = false)]
    public Data[] data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DataField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.DataField = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public Person personFiled;
    public Company companyFiled;

    public Person person
    {
        get
        {
            return this.personFiled;
        }
        set
        {
            this.personFiled = value;
        }
    }

    public Company company
    {
        get
        {
            return this.companyFiled;
        }
        set
        {
            this.companyFiled = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    /// some properties
}

public class Company
{
    /// some properties
}
```

At the moment, the external service has changed the structure of the XML response, now it looks like this:

```
<ns0:response xmlns:ns0='http://ws.gp.mnpartners.kz/services/bvu'>
<data>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns0:person">
        <request>
            <number>860517450246</number>
            <surname>Foo</surname>
            <name>Bar</name>
            <birthDate>1986-05-17</birthDate>
        </request>
    </item>
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns0:comapany">
        <request>
            <companyId>010940000162</companyId>
            <fullName>SomeCompanyName</fullName>
        </request>
    </item>
</data>
```

I want to get a ready object after deserialization, even if the person and company objects are in different arrays.

Advise the best approach to deserialize this XML please, any ideas.

Comment: Easiest way is to copy the request property that is in company/person to also be in item.  Than after serialization you can add checks to see if request exists in item.  Code will be backward/forward compatible.  Serialize does not require that all properties in the c# class be in the xml file.

Comment: The external service has switched to a polymorphic format where person and company derives from item, so you need to do the same. But you may need to configure the xml serializer in some way. Once you have a list of all items you can extract all the persons with `allItems.OfType<Person>()`

Comment: Is the above "now it looks like this" XML the entire response, or just a fragment?  Given the attribute `xsi:type="ns0:comapany"`, there ought to be an XML namespace `xmlns:ns0="some namespace"` defined somewhere in scope.

Comment: @dbc sorry i edited the post

Comment: Are you trying to consume both the old and new responses with the **same data model**?  Is there any way to know in advance whether the old or new versions are going to be returned?

Comment: @dbc I need to adapt the models to the new version of the external service responses)

Answer (score 0):

Xml was popular 20+ years ago. I think it is time for you to try some new technics, Newtonsoft.Json for example

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    JArray item = (JArray) JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true)
                                   .Replace("ns0:", "")
                                   .Replace("@xsi:", ""))["item"];

    Company company = item[1]["request"].ToObject<Company>();
    Person persony = item[0]["request"].ToObject<Person>();
```

and you will need only Person and Company classes

if you are not sure is person and company are always in the same order inside of xml, try Linq

```
   Company company=item.Where(x=> (string) x["type"]=="comapany")
                       .Select(x=> x["request"].ToObject<Company>())
                       .FirstOrDefault();
                       
    Person persony=item.Where(x=> (string) x["type"]=="person")
                       .Select(x=> x["request"].ToObject<Person>())
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```